# Find and replace custom values in a dataframe

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, na

I have the following dataframe where I want to replace all occurrences of `"Blank(s)"` and `NA`'s.

```
dat <- data.frame(
    "a"=c("Blank(s)", "1", "2", "Blank(s)", <NA>),
    "b"=c("Blank(s)", "1", "2", "Blank(s)", <NA>),
    "c"=c("Blank(s)", "1", "2", "Blank(s)", <NA>),
    "d"=c("Blank(s)", "1", "2", "Blank(s)", <NA>),
    "e"=c("Blank(s)", "1", "2", "Blank(s)", <NA>),
    "f"=c("Blank(s)", "1", "2", "Blank(s)", <NA>)
)
```

For the `NA`'s I have successfully found [a wonderful solution by Muhammad Ariz](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-replace-all-NA-values-in-a-data-frame-with-another-not-0-value-tp2125458p2125516.html):

```
x <- c(rnorm(5),rep(NA,3),rnorm(5))    # sample data 
dat <- data.frame(x,x)                 # make sample dataframe 
dat2 <- as.matrix(dat)                 # convert to matrix 
y <- which(is.na(dat)==TRUE)           # get index of NA values 
dat2[y] <- "your string"               # replace all NA values
```

and just use `as.data.frame(dat2)` to convert the matrix to a dataframe again.

To add a condition for `"Blank(s)"` I tried doing `y <- which(is.na(dat3)==TRUE || dat3=="Blank(s)")` but nothing happened.

I want to know if I can combine these conditionals so that next time I can just add a string, vector or `is.` functions, like a good old find and replace mechanism, ie:

```
y <- which(is.na(dat3)==TRUE || is.character(dat3)==TRUE || 
    is.equal(dat3)=="Blank(s)" || is.equal(dat3)==-1 || ...)
```

Note: I would love to have a function that performs fast because my original dataframe has 500,000 observations and 55 variables.

Comment: try using single `|` in `y <- which(is.na(dat3)==TRUE || dat3=="Blank(s)")`

Comment: @Ananta, could you make that an answer? It worked perfectly and I want to credit you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using single `|` in `y <- which(is.na(dat3)==TRUE || dat3=="Blank(s)")`

so,

```
y <- which(is.na(dat3)==TRUE | dat3=="Blank(s)")
```